# Haskell as a highly concurrent server

Tags: haskell, concurrency, io

Let's say I want to write a server in Haskell. The kind that has high concurrency and simple processing. The kind that would be robust to failures and offer high availability. The kind that Erlang would be good for.

What would be a good set of tools, whether a framework or a set of primitives, to start from?

Answer (score 20):

This is precisely what Haskell is great at. And it has excellent multicore parallelism support, so when you use more threads, you can take advantage of extra cores easily. Remember though, Haskell's aimed at great performance on multicore, Erlang's a bit different, emphasising distributed systems more, and not so much raw performance (e.g. see the benchmarks game, http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/compare.php?lang=ghc&lang2=hipe  The Haskell's almost always much faster and uses much less memory).

Now, to get started:

- You can start with the examples in Real World Haskell, to learn about forkIO and Haskell's lightweight threads, http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html
- GHC's docs on the concurrency tools, http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Concurrency
- The library to look at for massive, scalable network code is the event library: http://github.com/tibbe/event which makes it easy to use epoll as the method for accepting events from the network. Here's a simple example: http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/playing-with-the-new-haskell-epoll-event-library/
- For back to basics, see Simon Marlow's tutorial on building a concurrent web server: http://www.haskell.org/~simonmar/bib/webserverjfp_abstract.html

You should find this task relatively easy, and fun!

Comment: README of the event library indicates that it's been merged to ghc base libraries. Where I can find it? (it's my first day with haskell ;) ). I use GHC 6.12.1.

Comment: OK, found it `System.Event`.
If I understand correctly, it was merged with ghc 7 and is planned for 6.14 (http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/635). Is it right?

Comment: Probably worth noting that Haskell has separate facilities for parallelism and concurrency.

Comment: epoll is now built into the runtime.  No need to look at a separate event lib.  http://haskell-distributed.github.io/ is now also highly relevant if comparing to Erlang.

Answer (score 1):

Great place to start is the seminal paper by Simon Peyton Jones [The Awkward Squad](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/marktoberdorf/mark.pdf).

... I recently heard a talk you might find relevant. See details at the [galois website](http://www.galois.com/blog/2010/01/20/tech-talk-a-scalable-io-manager-for-ghc/)

Comment: @Kevin, almost, but you got some details wrong. Firstly, the speaker was Johan Tibell from Google/Youtube, and select() itself isn't a big problem (having 1024 simultaneous handles is a bit rare) -- and anyway, you don't need to wait, the event lib, which uses epoll, is already available: http://github.com/tibbe/event 

You can see details here: http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/playing-with-the-new-haskell-epoll-event-library/

Comment: And I strongly disagree that "there is a lot of stuff lacking in order to really kill it on the perf front server-side" -- performance is excellent, and a few million threads is easily doable today.

We build and benchmark concurrent servers all the time at Galois, and performance is rarely an issue -- Erlang's overheads are shocking in comparison (it is aimed at a different use case: distributed systems, not high perf. servers).

Comment: I think I'll take my foot out of my mouth and just edit the post back to where I started w/ the awkward squad.

Comment: Sorry for jumping on the comment like that, it's been a long day :}

Comment: Like your stack underflow avatar :)